# Linking two controllers in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, controllers

I have a signed in user profile and each profile has its own **phone-book** that no other user can access. The question is how should i implement it. Considering **User** as one controller and **phone-book** as another i'm not able to establish a relation between the two for a specific user login.

What should be my approach?

I have a sparate model for User and separate model for phone-book and have established a relation between them using **has_many** and **belongs_to** macro.

Comment: So basically you have successfully established the has many relationship between user & phone_book right? 
You just need to list those phone_book information in your users profile page (technically users_controllers profile/show action ). is it ?

Comment: Its not just about displaying the contacts to the user. The user should be able to perform CRUD operations on his personal contacts. Pleas bare with me, I'm new to Rails

Comment: Yes Understood now. Please check below answer.  Putting the phone-books resource inside the users will do the trick :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with the models. You say that each `User` has **only one** `PhoneBook` so I would say that the right models should rather be:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :phone_book
end

class PhoneBook < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Now, about the controllers.
When you have a signed in `User` you will eventually have a "session thing" going on.
Let's say you're using [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise), then you will have a variable `current_user` that references the logged in user. So the `PhoneBooksController` will be something like:

```
class PhoneBooksController < ApplicationController    
  def index
    @phone_book = current_user.phone_book
  end   
end
```

Of course if your users can have more than one `PhoneBook` we go back to the `has_many` association:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :phone_book
end

class PhoneBook < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

and the controller becomes:

```
class PhoneBooksController < ApplicationController    
  def index
    @phone_books = current_user.phone_books
  end
  def show
    @phone_book = PhoneBook.find_by_id(params[:id])
  end
end
```

At last, if you want these phone books to be publicly readable I suggest you stick with a [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) kind of URI

```
/phone_books/:id <-- good
/users/:id/phone_books/:phone_book_id <-- too complex
```

Hope I could help

Comment: Thanks for sharing your concept. Its working out for my project.
Can't up-vote your answer due to my low reputation.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to place the page in `/users/:user_id/phone_books/:id`.

To achieve that,

You have to configure the paths in `config/routes.rb`:

```
resources :users do
  resources :phone_books
end
```

And in `app/controllers/phone_books_controller.rb`, find the user and their address book:

```
class PhoneBooksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_user

  def show
    @address_book = @user.address_books.find(params[:id])
  end

  private

  def find_user
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  end
end
```

For more information about nested resources, please see the [Getting Started with Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#adding-a-route-for-comments) guide.

Comment: No route matches "/users/10/contacts/2" with {:method=>:get}.
I have contacts with id=2  and users with id =10 stored in the database.
contacts is analogous to phone_books

Comment: @pranavprashant On what page does the error happen? Did you try restarting the Rails server? Can you try running the `rake routes` command and update the result in the question?